# action server not starting

Tags: ros, action-server, turtlebot-arm, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation with ROS Hydro. I use action server but it doesn't start. I don't understand why. Here is my code :

```
  actionlib::SimpleActionServer<turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation::BlockDetectionAction> as_;
BlockDetectionServer(const std::string name) : 
    nh_("~"), as_(name, false), action_name_(name)
  {
    // Load parameters from the server.
    // Register the goal and feeback callbacks.
    as_.registerGoalCallback(boost::bind(&BlockDetectionServer::goalCB, this));
    as_.registerPreemptCallback(boost::bind(&BlockDetectionServer::preemptCB, this));
    
    std::cout<<"action server is active ? : "<<as_.isActive()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Start action server"<<std::endl;
    as_.start();
    std::cout<<"action server is active ? : "<<as_.isActive()<<std::endl;
```

and I got :

```
action server is active ? : 0
Start action server
action server is active ? : 0
```

Why is the action server not starting?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203555/action-server-not-starting/) by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

isActive returns if a goal is active not if the ActionServer is running. See the [API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionServer.html#abe518d6a22616909c4313eecd7941022)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2